# Get jenkins user list with bash inside pipeline job

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to get user list from specific group to array with bash inside jenkins job. I thought that I can use jenkins rest api with curl like download api/json, but I can't find any details about this

Does Jenkins have some opportunity to give me this list? I even did not find how to check groups with ui

Comment: This group is from Linux or in Jenkins or something other?

Comment: @Nigredon In jenkins. You can provide some specific permission with this group. And on the user page you can see these groups